# How to type Gmail Body text in Selenium2 (Webdriver) using Java

Tags: java, gmail, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng

I tried to automate sending email from Gmail (https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=http://mail.google.com/mail/&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2) by using Selenium WebDriver with Java. First I tried to record the test by using Selenium IDE. IDE failed to record the body of email.
I tried by the following way to type on body text, but it failed unfortunately.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@name='body']")).sendKeys("body text");

Error is: FAILED: testSendingEmail
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration or timeout: 30.02 seconds

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: I tried to type gmail message body by using the following:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@name='body']")).sendKeys("body text");

As the textarea is not visible on the page the following error was occurred: testSendingEmail org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration or timeout: 30.02 seconds

How can I type on Gmail or Yahoo mail message body? (textarea for message body is NOT visible on the page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the piece of HTML code for typing gmail body:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" style="padding: 0pt; height: 218px; background-color: white;" class="Am Al editable" id=":4z" tabindex="1"></iframe>
```

I have written the following java code in WebDriver to type gmail body and it worked nicely. (I am happy)

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebElement frame1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='Am Al editable']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame1);
WebElement editable = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
String mailBody = "Hi," + '\n' + "I'm Ripon from Dhaka, Bangladesh.";
editable.sendKeys(mailBody);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 2):

YES.. you can't record the **body of email** using **Selenium IDE**.

include the following method in your project and call that method to send Email.(No need to login into gmail)

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public void SendEmail()
{

  // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
  String to = "abcd@gmail.com";

  // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
  String from = "web@gmail.com";

  // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
  String host = "localhost";

  // Get system properties
  Properties properties = System.getProperties();

  // Setup mail server
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

  // Get the default Session object.
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

  try{
     // Create a default MimeMessage object.
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

     // Set From: header field of the header.
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

     // Set To: header field of the header.
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                              new InternetAddress(to));

     // Set Subject: header field
     message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

     // Now set the actual message
     message.setText("This is actual message");

     // Send message
     Transport.send(message);
     //System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
  }
catch (MessagingException mex) {
     mex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

You can also send **mail** with **Attachments**

Refer [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm) for more information.

Comment: if it's worked for you mark it as answer. So that if anyone is having the same problem, it's easy for them to chose the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks Ranadheer Reddy for your answer. It's not possible to record the body of email using Selenium IDE. But I have got one solution in WebDriver using java that is already mentioned as answer in this post

Comment: Your code looks good to work sending mail without interaction of browser which Selenium usually does.

Answer (score 2):

when using class it throws and error element not found its better to use table index.

```
        WebElement frame1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@tabindex='1']"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(frame1);
    WebElement editable = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
    String mailBody = "Hi," + '\n' + "Gmail Body";
    editable.sendKeys(mailBody);
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code to write in body area

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body[class='editable  LW-avf']")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body[class='editable  LW-avf']")).sendKeys("body text");
```

Comment: I tried that way, but it did not work. The error is: FAILED: testSendingEmail
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body[class='editable  LW-avf']"}
Command duration or timeout: 30.06 seconds

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();

WebElement text=driver.findElement(By.className("LW-avf"));

text.click();
text.sendKeys("Hello");

Please try using above code.