# WebDriver + TestNG Gmail a strange error

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, gmail

I tried to automate sending email from Gmail and worked with TestNG and Page Object pattern, browser FireFox, but first a part of code =)

I'm looking at locators with help annotation (Page Object pattern), and then goes to a function which I use in my test.

```
@FindBy (how=How.XPATH, using = "//div[@class='T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3']")
public WebElement writeMail;

@FindBy (how=How.XPATH, using = "//textarea[@class='vO']")
public WebElement adressTo;

@FindBy (how=How.XPATH, using = "//input[@class='aoT']")
public WebElement subjectOfMail;

@FindBy (how=How.XPATH, using = "//body[@role='textbox']")
public WebElement contentMail;

@FindBy (how=How.XPATH, using = "//div[@class='T-I J-J5-Ji aoO T-I-atl L3']")
public WebElement sendMail;

public void writeMail(String adress, String subject) {
    writeMail.click();
    adressTo.sendKeys(adress);
    subjectOfMail.sendKeys(subject);
    webDriver.switchTo().frame(webDriver.findElement(
            By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@tabindex,'1') and contains(@frameborder,'0')]"))); 
    webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//body[@role='textbox']")).sendKeys("Test");
    webDriver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    sendMail.click();
}
```

allegedly has to work, but the record goes only in address and topic fields, and after that test is failed and in log:

`" Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//body[@role='textbox']"}"`

But if I comment

```
//adressTo.sendKeys(adress);
//subjectOfMail.sendKeys(subject);
```

`webdriver` switches to `iframe` as planned and writes text  in letter body  and clicks a button "Send".

Please explain to me, why this code works fine as a simple java app, but not works correctly in when I use it in my test (TestNG) in my example?

Comment: Why on hell do you want to send an e-mail using the web interface and selenium? Please tell me there's a _really_ good reason for doing so (then I'd really be interested in it, as this seems to be a weird idea) or that it's just for educational purpose... Otherwise: use SMTP. It's made for sending mail, works totally fine and will not break with the next update of GMail's web interface.

Comment: This is not my whim. It a task on my job (Junior QA test engineer).

Comment: Well I might imagine there are reasons to do so in testing. Good luck with it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the solution of problem was found here [How to type Gmail Body text in Selenium2 (Webdriver) using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116577/how-to-type-gmail-body-text-in-selenium2-webdriver-using-java?rq=1), but I wonder why did the old hpath worked so weird. Everyone thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for a `<body>` element with `@role='textbox'`:

```
//body[@role='textbox']
```

but the element you're looking for actually is a `<div>` container:

```
<div id=":c9" class="Am Al editable LW-avf" hidefocus="true" aria-label="Inhalt der Nachricht" g_editable="true" role="textbox" contenteditable="true" tabindex="1" style="direction: ltr; min-height: 416px;"><br></div>
```

So use following XPath instead:

```
//div[@role='textbox']
```

Comment: Sorry, not works. Today i even cant get xpath to "body letter", but yesterday it worked. It seems like google changes his code every hour(